# JavaScript Search Bar that Scrolls to input ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript, and i'm still currently learning it as we speak.

I'm trying create a search bar that when a user types in a item name (Ex. Item 5) the search bar will scrollTo the item based off the input and the Div's tag. The site i'm working on is a long list of items, and the clients usually know what they are looking for.

I've seen a lot of examples of how to make a Button scroll to a Div, but not much on how to set up a input in a search bar to scroll to a Div.

The scrolling method would be nice if it was smooth. I would like it to based off of the number value of what they input in. So if it's a string for example "10.01A Paper" i'd like it to convert it to 1001A", and that will be what the div would be named. `<Div ID=1001A>` Does that make sense?

Any advice would be great!

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stinkytofu/gkehnkdk/)

```
<form id="searchbox" action="">
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
```

Item 1



Item 2



Item 3



Item 4

```
.space {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about the expected behaviour. Does the user have to type in the full name of the item for it to work? A prefix? A substring?

Comment: .. should there be smooth scroll or just jump?

Comment: The scrolling method would be nice if it was smooth. I would like it to based off of the number value of what they place in. So if it's a string for example "10.01A Paper" i'd like it to convert it to 1001A", and that will be what the div would be named? Does that make sense?

Comment: I assume using a toUpperCase() that would convert the string to all Capitals, but i want it to mostly to be able to determine what the item number is. All the items have a numerical value at the start for the product number, this is also how they choose what they order.

Comment: Case you missed it, I've added an answer with a simplistic and easy method, and it's smooth too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want, have fun with it.
https://jsfiddle.net/gkehnkdk/2/

The animation is in the lines:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
});
```

I've made it so you have to enter the "id" of the item you're searching. But you can change the code into something like checking the text of it. That's up to you now.

In my opinion this is the easiest and simplest solution, and it's smooth too.

**Edit as request by user**

To remove the dots from the string, simply add

```
myString.replace(/\./g, "");
```

after the string.

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gkehnkdk/6/

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That works great. What would be a good way to make it where if the user types "10.01A" that the input will ignore the "." and just look for "1001A" ?

Comment: String manipulation.  Replace the . with an empty string and then use the result of that.

Comment: After looking at the site i'm re-desgning i'm noticing that every item title is contained within a 'Span' tag.

<span class="dm-title">20.01B </span>

How can i modify this script to find the "string" within the 'span' tag. 
In this example it would be 20.01B.

Comment: Please post your code in a fiddle, if you just copy paste it here, it's too confusing to read.

Comment: Right now it will ScrollTo to the Span ID. How could i get it to scroll to the content within the Span ID. (Ex. Item 1)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/filipetedim/gkehnkdk/9/ there. I've commented, to make sure you learn as well.

Comment: Thanks Ted! This is great, and i can actually understand what's going on. I appreciate it. Hopefully i can figure this out of my own once i finish this JavaScript course.

Comment: No problems. Don't know what course you're taking, but https://www.codecademy.com/learn has some pretty neat stuff.

Comment: I first took the Code Academy course, but right now i'm doing the Tree House version. Still only halfway through the course though. What would be a good way to stop the submit button from refreshing the page? Every time i click the "search" button it scrolls correctly, but after it scrolls the entire page refreshes.

Comment: That happens because you have it in a form. Watch my example, and you'll see the button is not in a form. When it's in a form, and its type is ''submit', the page tries to submit the form, therefor refreshing the page in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLq7wgkp/):

```
var searchButton = document.getElementById('submit'),
    searchText   = document.getElementById('search');

// the text property is what the search input is compared against
// once a match is found, the id property is used to lookup the element
var items = [
    { text: 'Item 1', id: 'item1' },
    { text: 'Item 2', id: 'item2' },
    { text: 'Item 3', id: 'item3' },
    { text: 'Item 4', id: 'item4' }
];

function searchForItem(query) {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].text.indexOf(query) !== -1) {
            return document.getElementById(items[i].id);
        }
    }
}

searchButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var query = searchText.value,
        item  = searchForItem(query);
    if (typeof item !== 'undefined') {
        item.scrollIntoView();
    }
});
```

html:

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here"/>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Search" />


<div id="item1" class="space">Item 1</div>
<div id="item2" class="space">Item 2</div>
<div id="item3" class="space">Item 3</div>
<div id="item4" class="space">Item 4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way to have the browser scroll to a given element is to navigate to the ID of the element using the hash part of the URL.

With that in mind, try this javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('searchbox').onsubmit = function() {
          document.location.href = '#'+document.getElementById('search').value;
          return false;
    };
};
```

What that does is it "hi jacks" the default functionality of the form and instead of submitting the form the regular way, it simply changes the URL and navigates to # + the string you entered.

So entering 'item1' will cause the browser to navigate to #item1 which will make the browser scroll down to whatever element has the ID of item1, and so forth.

To have smooth scroll, you need to implement the scroll yourself using Javascript.  There are numerous scripts available, mostly depending on jQuery.

See here: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2/